# Troubles with [After*] Fixtures in Steps

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow, fixtures

### The Problem:

I have two features (I'm just getting started with SpecFlow)
In each of the feature steps, I create a global WebDriver so that I can use it for all of the steps. If I run just the steps, everything runs correctly in both features. They do, however, leave the browser window open because I never close the WebDriver. So my thought was to put an AfterFeature fixture in each of the Step files do close the driver.

```
[AfterFeature]
public static void ShutDown()
{
     Driver.Close();
}
```

When I run each feature, everything is fine and the driver closes at the end of the run. However, if I run more than one feature like this, the driver will close after the first feature and a new one will not open when the next feature starts. I find this odd since each feature steps file has it's own instantiated driver.

I have learned that if I use [AfterTestRun], the tests will run correctly and both browsers will remain open until all features are complete. At which point they will both close. This is ok for now when I only have two features, but when I get a bunch, I would rather not have a bunch of random browser windows sticking around until all the tests are completed.

I think this might be somehow related to my inability to use [AfterScenario] without breaking my tests. I was trying to use [AfterScenario] to logout after each scenario/test, but when I do I see a random blank driver/browser window pop up at the end of my first test (regardless of which test I run first).

I have this feeling that I'm just missing some sort of paradigm with this whole BDD methodology here, and that things are actually working as designed. But I am at a loss as to what changes I should make.  Here is an example of my login tests.. Is there something fundamental that I'm missing here?

### The Code:

```
Login.feature
Feature: Login
    In order to be able to use Laserfiche
    As a legitimate user
    I want to be able to log into the repository

@SmokeTest
Scenario: Login with correct credentials
    Given I am on the Login page 
    And I have a good username/password combination
    And I select a repository
    When I fill out the form and submit
    Then I am taken to the repo page

---------------
LoginSteps.cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Selenium_C_Sharp_POC.Page_Object_Files.Pages;
using Selenium_C_Sharp_POC.Page_Object_Files.Test_Tools;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Selenium_C_Sharp_POC.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public class LoginSteps
    {
        private static readonly IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();

        private static LoginPage _loginPage;
        private static string _username;
        private static string _password;
        private static string _repo;

        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void ShutDown()
        {
            Driver?.Close();
        }

        [Given(@"I am on the Login page")]
        public void GivenIAmOnTheLoginPage()
        {
            _loginPage = new LoginPage(Driver);
        }

        [Given(@"I have a good username/password combination")]
        public void GivenIHaveAGoodUsernamePasswordCombination()
        {
            _username = Nomenclature.WebClientPersonalUsername;
            _password = Nomenclature.WebClientPersonalPassword;
        }
        [Given(@"I select a repository")]
        public void GivenISelectARepository()
        {
            _repo = Nomenclature.RepoUnderTest;
        }

        [When(@"I fill out the form and submit")]
        public void WhenIFillOutTheFormAndSubmit()
        {
            _loginPage.Login(
                username: _username, 
                password: _password, 
                repo: _repo);
        }

        [Then(@"I am taken to the repo page")]
        public void ThenIAmTakenToTheRepoPage()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(
                expected: _repo,
                actual: Driver.Title);

            HelperMethods.Logout(Driver);
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:  Added Login Page Class code

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using Selenium_C_Sharp_POC.Page_Object_Files.Test_Tools;

namespace Selenium_C_Sharp_POC.Page_Object_Files.Pages
{
    class LoginPage
    {
        private readonly IWebElement _repoDropDown;
        private readonly IWebElement _usernameTextBox;
        private readonly IWebElement _passwordTextBox;
        private readonly IWebElement _submitButton;
        private readonly IWebDriver _driver;
        private readonly IWebElement _warningBox;

        public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;

            HelperMethods.OpenWebPage(
                domain: Nomenclature.Domain, 
                driver: _driver,
                subPage: Nomenclature.LoginPageFilename
                );

            _repoDropDown = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("SelectedRepo"));
            _passwordTextBox = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            _usernameTextBox = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
            _submitButton = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginButton"));
            _warningBox = _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("alert-danger"));
        }

        public void Login(string username, string password, string repo)
        {
           SelectRepo(repo);
           _usernameTextBox.SendKeys(username);
           _passwordTextBox.SendKeys(password);
           _submitButton.Click();
           WaitForLoginToComplete();
        }

        public void SelectRepo(string repo)
        {
            _repoDropDown.Click();
            var options =  _repoDropDown.FindElements(By.XPath(".//option"));
            foreach (var option in options)
            {
                if(option.Text.Equals(repo))
                    option.Click();
            }
        }

        public bool WarningDisplayed_UsernamePassword()
        {  
           Thread.Sleep(500);
           return _warningBox.Displayed &&
                  _warningBox.Text.Equals(Nomenclature.BadUsernameOrPasswordText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        internal bool OpenedRepoPage(string expectedRepo)
        {
            return _driver.Title.Equals(expectedRepo);
        }

        internal void WaitForLoginToComplete()
        {
            try
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("alert-danger")));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@ng-model='searchQuery']")));
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName("entryListLoadingSpinner")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## LatestInfo:

I believe I know ***why*** this is happening. I just don't know the proper way to fix it. As an experiment, I changed the WebDriver for my search tests to Firefox and left the WebDriver for my login tests as Chrome. No matter what test(s) I ran, I always saw 2 browsers open; one Chrome and one Firefox.

When I moved all of the steps from my SearchTestSteps.cs file into the LoginTestSteps.cs file, the problem disappeared.

So, yeah, this solves the immediate issue, but it is sub-optimal to have all of my steps in a single file. That can quickly become unwieldy.

Since each set of steps needs to have its own WebDriver, I'm at a loss.

Might this have something to do with folder structure and where things are stored? Here is what mine looks like.

```
Root
 |-Page Object Files
      |- Page Components
      |- Pages
      |- Test Tools  
 |- Step Definitions
      |- <*Steps.cs>  
 |- TESTS
      |- BDD Tests
          |-<*.feature>
      |- *standard selenium test files*
```

Comment: Can you show your loginpage class?

Comment: Appended to the entry above...
I changed the name of the function that opens the login page to "OpenWebPage" to obfuscate the company name...  :-)

Comment: It seems that this is not a problem with [After*] at all.
I removed all of them and I am now consistently seeing the blank web browser show up. This is frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating some more, I realized that the problem is **NOT** what I thought it was, and therefore the title and contents were inaccurate. I am closing this question and creating a new question with more accurate Title and information.

[Having Multiple Step Files Opens Multiple Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071795/having-multiple-step-files-opens-multiple-browsers)